# Powershell providing input from 1 column in Excel and getting output from another

Tags: excel, powershell

I've got Excel file with 2 columns - Column A has list of number codes and Column B has matching letter codes. A1 matches letter code from B1 etc...

```
Number Code
11111  AB
12345  GE
```

How can I get the letter code in output providing the number in Powershell?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I need this to work with Process Automation software. Honestly my knowledge of Powershell is almost non-existent. But using Powershell script and triggering it through the RPA software is only solution i can think of, because the application itself is not providing feature like that.

Comment: Unfortunately, StackOverflow isn't a code-writing service.  If you can get the data in CSV format rather than XLSX, then you can easily import it with built-in [Import-Csv](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv?view=powershell-6) cmdlet. Alternatively, you might want to check out the [ImportExcel](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ImportExcel/5.4.4) module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by creating a hash table. This allows you to specify a "key" and PowerShell will return the associated data. The key must be unique and not null (in your case the key would be the number.

Create a CSV with 2 columns, number and code.

```
# Import CSV into $csv variable

$csv = Import-CSV c:\csv.csv

# Create a new empty hash table

$csvHash = @{}

# Foreach row in the csv add the Number value as the key, and the code value as the associated data

$csv | % { $csvHash.Add($_.Number,$_.Code) }
```

You can then retrieve the associated letter code of a number like so:

```
$csvHash."11111"
```